# Access Field Values from JSON serialized django object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, django

I have a problem which is proving to be harder to find an answer for than I imagined.  I am using AJAX to update the select options based on a response from another select box.  I am able to correctly retrieve the right list of objects, serialized as json, but I can't access any of the field values of the object.

View:

```
def choose_group(request):
team_id = request.POST['team_id']

groups = WorkoutGroup.objects.filter(team_id=team_id)
data = serializers.serialize('json', groups)

return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$('#team').on('change', function(){
            var team_id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/create_workout/choose_group/',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}', team_id: team_id },
                success: function(data) {
                    var groups = $('#group');
                    $(groups).children().not(':first').remove();
                    if (data.length >= 1){
                        $.each(data, function(group){
                            $(groups).append('<option value=' + group['fields']['id'] + '>' + group['fields']['group_name'] +  '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                }

            }); 
        })
```

I get an error with all the ways I've tried to access the fields of each object (such as the id and group_name of the objects, as defined in the model).  The error is 'cannot read property of undefined'.

**EDIT:**

I have also tried just creating a ValueQuerySet and dumping it using simplejson, but I still cannot access any fields within, just 'undefined'.  Also, if I alert through each group, I get just the index of the iteration within the group list.

New View:

```
def choose_group(request):
team_id = request.POST['team_id']

groups = WorkoutGroup.objects.filter(team_id=team_id).values('id','group_name')
#data = serializers.serialize('json', groups)

return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(list(groups)), content_type='application/json')
```

and my Javascript now looks like this:

```
$('#team').on('change', function(){
            var team_id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/create_workout/choose_group/',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}', team_id: team_id },
                success: function(groups_list) {
                    var groups = $('#group');
                    $(groups).children().not(':first').remove();
                    if (groups_list.length >= 1){
                        //json = JSON.parse(data);
                        $.each(groups_list, function(group){
                            alert(group)
                            $(groups).append('<option value=' + group.pk + '>' + group.fields.group_name +  '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                }

            }); 
        })
```

Comment: show us the structure of response data

Comment: the response data uses djangos built in serializer to construct json in this format https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json

Comment: You need to add a sample of the `data` returned from the ajax call.

Comment: that doesn't show what is being sent ... show real sample copied from browser  dev tools network actual request or log it to your console in success callback

Comment: [{"model": "workout.workoutgroup", "fields": {"group_name": "Coach", "team": 7, "users": [12]}, "pk": 7}, {"model": "workout.workoutgroup", "fields": {"group_name": "Corner", "team": 7, "users": [35, 37]}, "pk": 8}]

--I can see now why id wouldn't work, that I need just group['pk'], however the group_name brings up the same problem but I cannot see that solution

Comment: You'll have an easier time getting to this data if you parse the response as JSON: `json = JSON.parse(data);` in your success callback.

Comment: trying to parse it throws an 'unexpected token o' error, which from looking around a bit seems to be because the data is already an object

Answer (score 1):

**Accessing the serialized django object**

To access the serialized django object you need to first parse the data variable like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

And then you can access the fields of each object Individually like this:

```
// for the first object
obj[0]['fields']['id']            // or  obj[0].fields.id
obj[0]['fields']['group_name']   // or  obj[0].fields.group_name

// for the second object
obj[1]['fields']['id']            // or  obj[1].fields.id
obj[1]['fields']['group_name']   // or  obj[1].fields.group_name

// and so on...
```

In your case you can do this:

```
$.each(obj, function(index){ // for each object
    $(groups).append('<option value=' + obj[index]['fields']['id'] + '>'+ obj[index]['fields']['group_name'] +  '</option>');                                                      
});
```